# Django ORM: Count, Max, and retrieve field associated with max

Tags: python-3.x, django

In my situation there's a table with 3 fields `A`, `B`, and `C`. I want to group by `A`, and also store how many occurrences there are of each distinct `A` (Count). I also want to retrieve the max `B` for each `A` group and the `C` that is associated with the max `B` for each group.

Only `C` has no duplicates.

Does anyone know how to do write such a query using Django ORM?

Comment: show your models..